# Implement Matching Algorithm in Ruby on Rails App

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, algorithm, matching

I've been building my job board for about 10 months now. I give users the ability to search and apply but I see a need to give them match results. I know there are numerous ways to go about matching but what is the most efficient way. Should I continue to write the matching algorithm in the user model, or as a module, or as a plugin? Currently I have started it in the model but it seems like it will get very messy.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


  attr_accessible :name, :provider, :uid, :bio, :gender, :location, :interests, :education, :jobs, :state, :city, :resume, :available, :website, :video_cover, :date_of_birth,
 :language, :skills

 class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :title, :company, :company_description, :industry, :requisition_number, :city, :state, :zipcode, :posted_ate, :experience, :job_type, :longitude, :latitude,  :recruiter_id, :apply_link, :contact_name, :contact_email, :job_id

def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
 end
```

Should I expand on the search method and create a match algorithm in the model user and job model or move it into a module?

Answer (score 2):

My opinion - if you see the functionality growing, extract it into a class. Like this:

```
class JobFilter
  def initialize(scope)
    @scope = scope
  end

  def filter(params)
    filter_by_title params[:title]
    ...
    @scope
  end

  private

  def filter_by_title(title)
    @scope = @scope.where('title LIKE ?', "%#{title}%")
  end

  ...
end
```

Then, you can call it like this: `matching_jobs = JobFilter.new(Job.all).filter({ title: 'CTO' })`.

The details of filtering are concentrated in one location, your User / Job models do not get messy as you add more and more matching params. As a bonus, it's easier to test.

Comment: I added models/job_filter.rb. Do I access the methods of this class through controllers/jobs_controller.rb or models/job.rb? Also, I add more private methods like :filter_by_city and call them in the :filter method.

Comment: I initialize and call filters where you need to limit a set of data based on bunch of parameters - that's usually in controller. As for private methods, I view `filter` as the router method: you give it a heap of parameters, it figures out what to do with them and calls the relevant methods that implement filtering by that one parameter. And since you usually don't need to call those smaller methods directly, you can leave them as private.